# Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute (formArray)

Tags: angular, formarray

Hi guys i'm trying to build a rective form, which has a formArray and i want to be able to add or remove input fields dynamically but i get the error: 
*Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute*

here's my code:

the ts file:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-create-ilm-policy',
 templateUrl: './create-ilm-policy.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./create-ilm-policy.component.scss']
})

export class CreateIlmPolicyComponent implements OnInit {

    mainForm:FormGroup

    constructor(){}

    get patterns(){
    return <FormArray>this.mainForm.get('indexPatterns')
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.mainForm = new FormGroup({
       indexPatterns: new FormArray([this.addIndexPattern()]),
       rolloverAlias: new FormControl()
      })
    }

     addIndexPattern(): FormControl{
     return new FormControl()
     }

     removeIndexPatternRow(index: number) {
     (<FormArray>this.mainForm.get('indexPatterns')).removeAt(index)
     }

     addIndexPatternRow(){
     (<FormArray>this.mainForm.get('indexPatterns')).push(this.addIndexPattern())
     }
}
```

the html file:

```
<form [formGroup]="mainForm">
<div formArrayName="indexPatterns" *ngFor="let pattern of patterns.controls; index as i">

      <div class="d-flex align-items-center" [formControl]="i">

        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>modèle d'indices</mat-label>
          <input matInput [formControl]="patterns.controls[i]"> <!--line that throws the error!!!!!!!-->
          <mat-hint>ajouter * à la fin</mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-icon class="pointer" color="warn" (click)="removeIndexPatternRow(i)" svgIcon="delete_forever" aria-hidden="false"></mat-icon>

      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: IMK, when we have a `[formGroup]` we pass the `[formControlName]` instead of actual controls and we let angular pick the control itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using [formControl] to set the name and the FormArray use the index as a name and should be defined using [formControlName]

```html
<form [formGroup]="mainForm">
  <div formArrayName="indexPatterns" *ngFor="let pattern of patterns.controls; index as i">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>modèle d'indices</mat-label>
        <input matInput [formControlName]="i" />
        <!--line that throws the error!!!!!!!-->
        <mat-hint>ajouter * à la fin</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>

      <!-- <mat-icon
        class="pointer"
        color="warn"
        (click)="removeIndexPatternRow(i)"
        svgIcon="delete_forever"
        aria-hidden="false"
      ></mat-icon> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thank youu,i have solved the problem by removing the [formControl] in the div but your solution made it even cleaner.